# Post Azure VM creation bootstrap process - Azure user-data mechanism during VM creation?

Tags: azure, chef, winrm, knife

After creating an Azure Windows VM, how does bootstrapping (winrm or ssh) completed?

I'm using knife azure and using either winrm or ssh, the VM is created but fails to bootstrap.

Do I have to start with an image / VHD that already has winrm or ssh set up appropriately for the bootstrap to work?

Updated to add:

> Before any WinRM related knife subcommands will function correctly a
>   node's WinRM installation must be configured correctly. The below
>   settings should be added to your base server image (AMI) or **passed in
>   using some sort of user-data mechanism provided by your cloud
>   provider.**

[from here](https://github.com/opscode/knife-windows#nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is currently no way to pass a script to automatically run at startup to a vanilla, unaltered gallery image when creating a VM in Azure.

I worked around this limitation by creating a new machine, adding the correct winrm config, and them converted this into a virtual machine image.

I then use this image when creating a new vm via knife azure & chef.

The bootstrapping then works correctly.

Comment: You say you created your own image and the "I then use this image when creating a new vm via knife azure & chef." Doing a knife azure vm image create will only let you work with images that are in the list provided by knife azure image list and these are only the MS defined ones. Did you have to do something special ?